# Помогите написать класс на php

Tags: классы, php

Необходимо написать класс на PHP для генерации текстов по заданному шаблону.

В классе должна быть публичная функция, которой передаётся 1 параметр - шаблон. Эта функция должна вернуть сгенерированный текст.

Пример шаблона: (Здравствуйте|Добрый день), Евгений.(| Сегодня (прекрасная|плохая|ужасная) погода, не так ли?| Как Вы (поживаете|себя чувствуете)?)

В круглых скобках(группах) фразы разделены символом |. Из группы выбирается одна случайная фраза. Группы могут содержать неограниченное количество подгрупп. Таким образом из примера-шаблона могут получиться лишь следующие фразы: - Здравствуйте, Евгений. - Добрый день, Евгений. - Здравствуйте, Евгений. Сегодня прекрасная погода, не так ли? - Добрый день, Евгений. Как Вы поживаете? и т.д.

я вообще не понимаю как это реализовать... вот то что куралесил я:

```
class TZ {
    public function shablon ($name, $text) {
    $shablon = explode(",", $name);
            foreach ($shablon as $key => $value) {
        echo "Привет ".$value."<br />";
    }
}
}
$tz = new TZ;
if (isset($_POST['go'])){
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
$text = htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']);
$tz->shablon($name, $text);
}
```

Comment: @kiberchainik, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/230900/php-разбить-строку-на-массив

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Необходимо написать класс на PHP для генерации текстов по заданному шаблону

Это форум, где люди общаются, общение начинается со строк приветствия и т.п.

Самое обидное, что вы даже не удосужились прогуглить по запросу [класс на PHP для генерации текстов по заданному шаблону](https://www.google.ca/?gws_rd=cr&ei=1ig6UuPJF6PsyQG3iIH4BA#q=%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81+%D0%BD%D0%B0+PHP+%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F+%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83+%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83)

Первая же ссылка привела на ответ с решением такой же задачи, решенной еще в 2012 году.

[получить ответ](http://www.cyberforum.ru/php-oop/thread681489.html)

Надеюсь вы получите пять.
Хорошего дня.